# Select specified nodes and edges in vis.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vis.js, vis.js-network

I created a small network with less than 100 nodes and I wish to select some specified nodes and edges like:

> desiredNodes=[nodeId1,nodeId2...], desiredEdges=[edgeId1,edgeId2...].

The default `network.selectEdges()` and `network.selectNodes()` both have `unselectAll` built in and I could not figure out how to disable `unselectAll`.

I have tried

```
mySelection = {nodes: desiredNodes, 
highlightEdges: false, 
edges: desiredEdges};
network.setSelection(mySelection);
```

But in this case, all edges connected to `desiredNodes` are selected and the result is exactly like `network.selectNodes(desiredNodes,true)`.

Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/#methodSelection), `setSelection` takes an optional second argument where you can supply configuration options like `highlightEdges`.

```
mySelection = {
    nodes: desiredNodes, 
    edges: desiredEdges
};

myOptions = {
    highlightEdges: false
};

network.setSelection(mySelection, myOptions);
```

The other available configuration option happens to be `unselectAll`, so you could try disabling that in the options object too.